# Line break in a Popup box in Leaflet

Tags: python, leaflet, web-mapping, folium

How can I put a line break in the popup window in the following statement? I am trying \n and 
 but its not working.

```
for lt, ln, el, plc in zip(lat, lon, elev, pl):
    fga.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lt, ln], popup= "Place is " + plc + \n +"Magnitude of " + str(el),
    icon=folium.Icon(color=color_producer(float(el)))))
```

Comment: did you tried to use a html breakline `<br>`?

Comment: This didn't work.  `popup= "Place is " + plc + <br> +"Magnitude of " + str(el),`

Comment: You woulöd need to place the br inside the string. something like `"Place is" + plc + "<br> Magnitude of: " + str(el)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

- Leaflet popups can be styled with html strings
- Linebreaks, therefore, can be produced by using the `<br>` tag inside a string

An example could look like this:

```
pop_up_text = "Some text <br> and some other text in a new <br><b>bold line</b>"
```

Also have a look at [the documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#popup) with its example

Answer (score 0):

A line break CR with "\r" works.

```
map.on('click', function(e) {alert(L.Projection.Mercator.project(latlng) + "\r \r \r Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)});
```